# Finding $y(1)$ from $y'=\sin(x)/x$ with $y(0)=0$ using Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Using the Euler's method (with $h=10^{-n}$) to find $y(1)$
$$y'=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
Since
$$y'(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
then
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
I know
$$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+h\cdot f(x_{n},y_{n})$$
and given $y(0)=0$, so
$$x_{0}=y_{0}=0$$
Therefore,
$$x_{1}=x_{0}+h=0+10^{-0}=1\Rightarrow y_{1}=y(x_{1})=y(1)$$
Then,
$$y_{1}=0+10^{-0}\cdot f(x_{0},y_{0})$$
$$y_{1}=f(0,0)$$
But
$$f(0,0)=\frac{\sin(0)}{0}=\frac{0}{0}$$
How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Use the limiting value of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, which can be computed via L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Nitpicking: @AndrewMcMillan : No, it can not be computed via l'Hopital. That would require to compute the derivative of the sine at $x=0$, which is the limit of the difference quotient which leads back to the exact same expression. Of course one could directly say that the limit is the derivative of the sine evaluated at $x=0$, and take the knowledge of what the derivative is from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use boundary condition $y(0)=1$ (i.e. consistent boundary condition) to keep the right hand side continuous. In other words, you have to solve a bit different problem
\begin{align}
y'(x)=\Bigg\{\begin{array}{l}
~~~1~~~~~~~~\text{if}~x=0\\
\frac{\sin x}{x}~~~~~~\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\end{align}
Otherwise it is not solvable. (The right hand side must be defined in the starting point $0$, where $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not.)